# How to update YAML of an Rmarkdown file to add plain text to title page

Tags: text, yaml, r-markdown

My YAML currently looks like this and is wrong so I am just posting it to give an idea.

```
---
title: "Autoscreening Report"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
text: "Some Text"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    toc: yes
---
```

I have purposefully added text as an option (to demonstrate the point) although text as an option does not exist. So how can I add plain text so that it appears on title page once I knit to PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Use this section:

````
```text

```
````

Your example:

````
---
title: "Autoscreening Report"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    toc: yes
---

```text
Tonight I will drink tea and eat cakes.
```
````

[image]